# Identify Features Incorrect Selection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, features, identify

The identify features tool returns the wrong selection when I try to select multiple features. In the image, I am trying to select the orange region, but QGIS is identifying the red region (located right above the popup window).

[image: Identify Features Incorrect Selection]

Note that clicking a single feature works correctly, only the "click-and-drag" works incorrectly.

I have tried the following:

1. Using GeoPandas to convert the shapefile (originally in ESRI:102003) to EPSG:4326 before loading into QGIS. This does not allow me to select any features at all with the "click-and-drag" method (even when the project CRS is EPSG:4326). This change in behvaior makes me think the issue is with some CRS setting.
2. Updating QGIS to 3.14.1

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, so probably it is a CRS issue, yes.

Comment: I'd check the geometries for validity errors - these can cause undefined behaviour like this

Comment: @ndawson Thanks. I just ran the Geometry Checker Plugin to check for validity errors and am still having the same issue on the valid geometries.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: @underdark Thanks. I have now posted it here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38052

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else runs into this, I fixed it by resetting my user profile in settings>user profiles>new profile