# Number of features decreases when saving selected features to new layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, export, features, select

I'm selecting features from a dataset using an expression. After selection, the selected features are a total of 6349.

[image: Original selection]

I save the selected using export -> save selected features as, and I've tried both as a shapefile and geopackage. When I open the attribute table of the new layer there are only 2707 features. What could be going wrong?

Edit: using qgis 3.30.0

original layer is a csv with wkt polygons

it seems like it just randomly skips some, i get the same result when using "extract selected features" tool

[image: New layer]

Comment: Would it be possible to test your data? What QGIS version are you working with? What is the origin of the data, e.g. a vector layer, a database, etc.?

Comment: Just curious if you get the same output, if you apply an extra step via the ["Extract selected features"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissaveselectedfeatures) and only after you export.

Comment: Are the results random or did you get the same 2707 exported feature each time ? Does the non exported feature have something in common (like a null geometry or a different geometry type) ? What message did you get after exporting ?

Comment: possible issue is the qgis profile > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368847/identify-features-incorrect-selection

Comment: Whenever I got odd results I always ran the Check Geometry tool as a first step.  In the case of the csv if you exported to a shapefile the entire layer do you get all of the polygons, and then if you run the selection or extraction on the shapefile do you still get drops?

Comment: So when I check validity or save the full csv laver as a shp file it actually also decreases number of features to about half.. so I guess not all rows of the original dataset is a polygon then?